# Is TLD .local not a local TLD anymore?

Tags: networking, domain, local, tld

I used to use .local as TLD for small household networks however I got a popup that I wasn't allowed to use it anymore after a firmware upgrade of an Asus Router. I choose now for .lan as internal TLD. Apart from MS Technet / MS best practice / issues with Apple devices to stop using .Local anymore is there any other reason to stop using it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `.local` is assigned as a [Special-Use Domain Name](https://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml) by IANA, as it's used by Multicast DNS ([RFC 6762, 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#section-3)). [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-2) specifies `.test`, `.example`, `.invalid` and `.localhost` for testing & documentation examples. Therefore, they should never be registered as official TLDs, but they do have some special purposes, as described in [RFC 6761, 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6).

I wouldn't use `.lan` as it's not on the IANA list, although it's listed on RFC 6762 [Appendix G](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#appendix-G).

Then, there's the Special-Use Domain `home.arpa.`, [RFC 8375](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375), 3:

> The domain name `home.arpa.` is to be used for naming within
> residential homenets.  Names ending with `.home.arpa.` reference a
> zone that is served locally, the contents of which are unique only to
> a particular homenet and are not globally unique.  Such names refer
> to nodes and/or services that are located within a homenet (e.g., a
> printer or a toaster).
>
> DNS queries for names ending with `.home.arpa.` are resolved using
> local resolvers on the homenet.  Such queries MUST NOT be recursively
> forwarded to servers outside the logical boundaries of the homenet.

Does that fit your needs for *small household networks*?

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: imo simply .home is in Appendix G, which you linked, for this specific purpose